# Problem figure names containing points

Tags: graphics

I have several graphics named with sample's label and I want to include these graphs in my document. The problem is that the file's name contains points, for example, RT1_0.1.pdf.

When I try to include using `\includegraphics`, I get the error message that LaTeX does not recognize the extension .1.pdf. Since I have several graphs and the dot is important to label the samples, is there a way to add figures with this kind of filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use braces to delimite the name:

```
\includegraphics{{RT1_0.1}.pdf}
```

Comment: Great. A simple solution that I didn't know about.